# Взаймодействие между UI и дочерним потоком и передача данных

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, .net-4.0

Простое WinForms приложение (TrayIcon и формочка с гридом), при пуске которой запускается с параллельным рабочим потоком, задача которого в цикле выполнять ресурсоемкую задачу. Результат задачи логируется в гриде формы UI.

Однако, иногда, при определенных результатах получаемых рабочим потоком, необходимо решение пользователя, включая и ручной ввод некоторых параметров, и дальнейшая обработка данных рабочим потоком будет производится согласно решению и вводимых данных.

Как организовать ждущий режим рабочему потоку, передать сигнал вместе с данными основному потоку об запросе ответа и передача обратно, рабочему потоку, из основного процесса приложения, данных вводимые пользователем? 
Какие шаблоны/конструкции посоветуйте?

Comment: А какая версия языка? **До** awync/await?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, проще всего использовать `form.Invoke(callback)`.

Это вызывает ваш `callback` (то есть, ваш код) в UI-потоке, и возвращает управление рабочему потоку только тогда, когда `callback` закончит свою работу. В коде `callback`'а вы можете показывать результаты и вводить данные от пользователя.

Для того, чтобы дождаться ввода пользователя в таком коде, проще всего показывать запрос в модальном диалоге, показанном при помощи `ShowDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

@VladD для взаимодействия с UI действительно InvokeRequired/Invoke, как говорится это уже классика...

Для решения передачи управления основному потоку приложения из дочернего рабочего использовал делегаты с сигналами (в частности EventWaitHandle).

Всем спасибо.